# Configure vscode to run tests with AWS profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code

I want to run tests against my AWS environment using a run configuration in vscode.

The tests need access to the AWS account to retrieve information like the name of a bucket, a user pool id ..

I have my credentials configured in `~/.aws/credentials` under `[dev-user]` like:

```
[dev-user]
aws_access_key_id=*************
aws_secret_access_key=***************************************
```

I can run this from the command line with `export AWS_PROFILE=dev-user` and then `npm run test`.

How do I create a launch config in vscode that does the same? Currently it is not working. I've tried the following: adding env variables or a prelaunch task. But neither of them work:

Env vars:
`launch.json`

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "name": "vscode-jest-tests",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": ["--runInBand"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "console": "internalConsole",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
      "env": { "AWS_PROFILE": "dev-user"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Pre launch task:
`launch.json`

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "name": "vscode-jest-tests",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": ["--runInBand"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "console": "internalConsole",
      "preLaunchTask": "setProfile",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest"
    }
  ]
}
```

`tasks.json`

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "setProfile",
      "command": "export AWS_PROFILE=dev-user",
      "args": ["test"],
      "type": "shell"
    }
  ]
}
```

None of the above gives me access to the AWS account from my tests.
How do I need to configure `launch.json` and / or `tasks.json` to get access to the AWS account in my tests?

Comment: Have you ever thought about using the AWS SDK for JS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html?

Comment: Yes, I am using the SDK. But how can I pass a profile to my script so that it uses the right credentials?

Comment: I am not very proficient in NodeJS, but shouldn't it be something like this: `process.env.AWS_PROFILE`? Could that work?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that adding `"env": { "AWS_PROFILE": "dev-user"}` to your configuration in `launch.json` does work.

So this is correct:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "name": "vscode-jest-tests",
      "request": "launch",
      "args": ["--runInBand"],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "console": "internalConsole",
      "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
      "disableOptimisticBPs": true,
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/jest/bin/jest",
      "env": { "AWS_PROFILE": "dev-user"}
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help anyone, but for me I had a key and password that should be sent in the request, I downloaded aws plugin and it didn't work, searching a lot I managed to solve it, you will have to post vscode and edit the launch file, the vscode has "env" property for variables .... I did it like this:
....
env": {
"AWS_DEFAULT_REGION":"xxxxxx",
"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
"AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).