# Can VSCode use AWS Toolkit credentials for running file

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, aws-toolkit

I'm new to VScode and trying to figure out if there's a simple way to implement this.
Essentially I've a lot of AWS accounts / profiles and for local testing I need to be able to switch between the accounts , run something and then check the logs.

However when I click run it's using the default credentials I have

[image: Connected as other account but showing buckets from default account]

Is there a correct way of getting the "Run" feature to use whatever AWS Toolkit profile is selected at the time?

My use case is that 99% of the time I will want to create a random ad-hoc script to do something simple and want to avoid having to mess with config files.

If this isn't possible is there a recommended way to quickly switch

Answer (score 1):

You should have a AWS ToolKit extension widget in the bottom left hand corner of the window.

[image: AWS Extension Widget]

Clicking it will bring up this menu to select from your locally configured credentials.

[image: Credential Menu]

Comment: So I've tried that but even with the profile selected it seems to be using my base credentials 

https://ibb.co/qsgvwFQ

and what we see when running in VS with the profile selected and loaded -> https://ibb.co/1MMzp0B

Comment: So the terminal itself could be set up to source [previously configured credentials via AWS CLI](https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/issues/1609#issuecomment-811141566). When you set-up the configuration profiles did you create them via the VSCode command palette using [AWS Toolkit Create Credentials Profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/setup-credentials.html)? Alternatively, if the profiles vary from project to project, you can specify the AWS Profile to use for each in [launch.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65500570/14436643) env configuration.

Answer (score 0):

[How to configure VSCode for multiple AWS Accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71703683/152142) provides some solutions:

- In your code, call
  `boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='profile-name')`
- Set `"env": { "AWS_PROFILE": "dev-user"}` in the relevant launch.json item. ([Full example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65500570/152142) for reference).

> I will want to create a random ad-hoc script to do something simple and want to avoid having to mess with config files.

Not currently possible with AWS Toolkit. The details of how the SDK (`boto3` in your example) can get the credentials, are not obvious (environment variables?). The "Play" button in your screenshot is provided by the vscode Python extension, not AWS Toolkit.

A related idea is for the current AWS Toolkit credentials to flow into vscode Terminals. Work in progress for that: https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-vscode/pull/3040